Starting error while integration with ELK
Getting following error message while starting apimanager.
Getting following error message while starting apimanager. 

Error:
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : Unable to locate appender "PaxOsgi" for logger config "root"
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : Unable to locate appender "CARBON_CONSOLE" for logger config "root"
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : Unable to locate appender "ERROR_LOGFILE" for logger config "root"
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : Unable to locate appender "CARBON_LOGFILE" for logger config "root"
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : Unable to locate appender "PaxOsgi" for logger config "root"
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : Unable to locate appender "CARBON_CONSOLE" for logger config "root"
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : Unable to locate appender "ERROR_LOGFILE" for logger config "root"
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : Unable to locate appender "CARBON_LOGFILE" for logger config "root"

My log4j2.properties settings:

#### ELK Config ############
appenders = APIM_METRICS_APPENDER
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.type = RollingFile
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.name = APIM_METRICS_APPENDER
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.fileName = ${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/apim_metrics.log

.
.
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.policies.size.size=1000MB
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.strategy.max = 10
loggers = reporter
logger.reporter.name = org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.reporter.elk
logger.reporter.level = INFO
logger.reporter.additivity = false
logger.reporter.appenderRef.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.ref = APIM_METRICS_APPENDER



Is my log4j2.properties setting is correct.
Sample example for basic ELK integration for WSO2 apimanager.



There was error corrected.



Now getting following error:


ERROR - AnalyticsMetricsHandler Error Occurred when collecting data
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.isEmpty()" because "this.successMetricReporters" is null

Can you share the full error log to identify the issue, and mention the product version as well
